# UIImageView's don't appear on first time view when being segued to from another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have VC1, which segues to VC2.  VC2 has some UIImageView's that should be displayed in viewDidLoad()--however the first time I land on VC2, the images are not shown. If I go to the next page of the app, then come back to VC2, the images are now there. I checked and the UIImageView's are not nil the first time landing on VC2, so I'm not sure why they don't appear the first time, and why they do appear all other times? My code for VC2 is below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var safeIcon: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var eaIcon: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.nameTitle.text = "\(firstName)'s Safe".uppercaseString

    self.safeIcon.image = UIImage(named: "safe icon")
    self.eaIcon.image = UIImage(named: "EA Logo")

    println(safeIcon)

}
```

I'm wondering if this has anything to do the segue from VC1 to VC2, which is done in a function like this:

```
func segueToApp(sender: AnyObject) -> Void {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self)

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite an answer yet, but what happens if you set the images in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`? Does that help, or is it the same?

Comment: Did you link safeIcon and eaIcon @IBOutlets to storyboard properly. It looks like they are not linked properly, the linking may be happening between 1st load and 2nd load. so check if the linking is proper or not.

Comment: @gregheo Tried that, but same result

Comment: @iKrish Yes the linking is correct--if it wasn't, I don't think the images would show up the consecutive times I land on VC2

Comment: I don't see any other reason, print the frame of the ImageViews and print self.safeIcon, self.safeIcon.image, self.eaIcon and self.eaIcon.image objects at the end of viewDidLoad method.

Comment: For println(self.safeIcon.frame), println(self.safeIcon), println(self.safeIcon.image) I get: (145.0, 135.0, 85.0, 80.0), <UIImageView: 0x7f9aa2659de0; frame = (145 135; 85 80); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9aa2654a70>>, Optional(<UIImage: 0x7f9aa2484f40>, {110, 106})  when I land on VC2 initially

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and I guess did not provide enough information here--the segueToApp function was being called from within an NSURL session (after some JSON was retrieved). Previously I was not calling the function from the main queue, but when I did the UIImageViews began showing up on VC2 on the first time.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.segueToApp(self)
}
```